# Tkinter not displaying label with number

Tags: python, tkinter

I've just started with tkinter and I ran into a problem, the label in the code below is supposed to display a rather long number (0.7522488614550792) but unfortunately it does not, the only thing visible is a little bit of the frame of the label (even when i enlarge the window), the code is not giving me any error so i'm not sure what i did wrong. Thank you for any help

The label:

```
label = Label(root, textvariable=extentIndex, relief=RAISED)
label.pack()
```

The whole code:

```
 def select_image():
 global panelA, panelB, panelC
 path = filedialog.askopenfilename()

    [...]

    if panelA is None or panelB is None or panelC is None:
        # the first panel will store our original image
        panelA = Label(image=original)
        panelA.image = original
        panelA.pack(side="top", padx=10, pady=10)

        # while the second panel will store the edge map
        panelB = Label(image=binary)
        panelB.image = binary
        panelB.pack(side="right", padx=10, pady=10)

        panelC = Label(image=ROI)
        panelC.image = ROI
        panelC.pack(side="left", padx=10, pady=10)

        ###THIS IS THE LABEL###

        **label = Label(root, textvariable=extentIndex, relief=RAISED)
        label.pack()**

    # otherwise, update the image panels
    else:
        # update the pannels
        panelA.configure(image=original)
        panelB.configure(image=binary)
        panelC.configure(image=ROI)
        panelA.image = original
        panelB.image = binary
        panelC.image = ROI

# initialize the window toolkit along with the two image panels
root = Tk()
panelA = None
panelB = None
panelC = None

btn = Button(root, text="Select an image", command=select_image)
btn.pack(side="bottom", fill="both", expand="yes", padx="10", pady="10")

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: i did this is the label: label = Label(root, textvariable=extentIndex, relief=RAISED)
        label.pack()

Comment: are you sure `panelA panelB panelC` are all `None`?

Answer (score 0):

found the problem, once i changed "textvariable" to "text" it started working, so from:

```
label = Label(root, textvariable=extentIndex, relief=RAISED)
```

to

```
label = Label(root, text=extentIndex)
```

tutorialspoint might have an outdated formula for it

Comment: `Tkinter` has it's own variables. you can also try declaring `extentIndex` as a `StrigVar` for example `extentIndex = Tk.StringVar()` and then you use `get` and `set` methods.